# Speeding up this recursive procedure in python

Tags: python, performance, recursion, graph

Given a graph H, I have to find all graphs g that fulfill a special requirement (which I call requirement2). All these graphs are stored in a set s. The graphs g must have the same number of vertices as H and all graphs are directed. So in essence, I am finding edges that I can add to g to satisfy requirement2. I notate my graphs using a dictionary so for example:

```
H = {
'1': {'1': set([(0, 1)])},
'3': {'3': set([(0, 1)]), '2': set([(0, 1)])},
'2': {'1': set([(0, 1)]), '3': set([(0, 1)]), '2': set([(0, 1)])},
}
```

means that there is an edge from vertex 1 to 1 and an edge from 3 to 2 etc...Please ignore the set([(0, 1)])'s for now for they are not relevant to my question. To find these g's that satisfy requirement2, I add an edge to an empty graph g with the same number of vertices as H and then use requirement1 to get an array of edges that I know might potentially work for satisfying requirement2. Then I add one of those edges deemed ok by requirement1 to g and test requirement2. Why I do not directly use requirement2 is that it would be way too time consuming to add every edge that g does not have and then test requirement2 on it. Early pruning saves time for me. I proceed with a Depth first search and if requirement 1 returns an empty array, I know I have to backtrack. The current code I have uses memoization to store subproblem solutions but this code is still not fast enough...With 7 nodes, this code can take 2500 seconds to run. Any suggestions on how to speed this up would be appreciated.

A little more on some functions this code uses:

addanedge(g,e) adds edge e to g

delanedge(g,e) deletes edge e in g

edgelist(g) returns a list of edges of g

complement(g) returns a list of edges that g does not have

requirement1(H,g) returns T if g fulfills some requirement 
involving H and F otherwise. It's purpose is for pruning down the number of edges I need to add for each round.

requirement2(H,g) returns T if g fulfills some requirement involving H and F otherwise. If true, I add g to s

memo stores my subproblem solutions

gsig simply converts the graph g to a form that I can add to a set.

```
def findgs(H):    
    g = {n:{} for n in H} 
    s = set()
    @memo                      
    def addedges(g,H,edges):
        if edges:
            masks  = [] 
            for e in edges:
                addanedge(g,e)
                if requirement1(H,g):
                    masks.append(False)
                else:
                    masks.append(True)
                delanedge(g,e)
            nedges = [edges[i] for i in range(len(edges)) if masks[i]] 
            n = len(nedges)
            if n:
                for i in range(n):
                    addanedge(g,nedges[i])
                    if requirement2(H,g):
                        s.add(gsig(g))
                    addedges(g,H,nedges[:i]+nedges[i+1:])
                    delanedge(g,nedges[i])

    edges = edgelist(complement(g))
    addedges(g,H,edges)
    return s

def memo(func):
    cache = {}                        
    @wraps(func)                     
    def wrap(*args):                  
        s = tool.signature(args[0],args[2])
        if s not in cache:            
            cache[s] = func(*args)    
        return cache[s]               
    return wrap
```

One thing I have noticed is that the same graphs that satisfy requirement2 appear MANY times and are cut out because s is a set and duplicates are not allowed.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using your own special graph representation, and not an optimized and tested library like `networkx`?

Comment: due to the fact that requirement1 and requirement2 are written by someone else and use that special graph representation